# How do i make this program re-run from the beginning after the input "yes"

Tags: python-3.3

```
print("1, Rice")
print("2, Amala")
print("3, Semolina")
print("4, Chicken")


Mainchoice=int(input("Select a number of choice:"))
if(Mainchoice==1):
    print("1, Rice and Beans with meat/fish.")
    print("2, Jollof Rice and chicken wings.")
    print("3, Fried Rice and Beef.")
    Rice=int(input("Select a Rice of choice:"))
    if(Rice==1):

        print("You selected Rice and Beans with meat/fish.")

    elif(Rice==2):

        print("You selected Jollof Rice and Chicken wings.")
    elif(Rice==3):

        print("You selected Fried Rice and Beef.")
    else:
        print("Please select a valid number from the list above.")

elif(Mainchoice==2):
    print("1, Amala and ewedu with beef.")
    print("2, Amala and efo riro with assorted meat.")
    print("3, Amala and egusi soup with meat.")
    Amala=int(input("Select an Amala of choice:"))
    if(Amala==1):
        print("You selected Amala and ewedu with beef.")
    elif(Amala==2):
        print("You selected Amala and efo riro with assorted meat.")
    elif(Amala==3):
        print("You selected Amala and egusi with meat.")
    else:
        print("Please select a valid number from the list.")
elif(Mainchoice==3):
    print("1, Semolina and Ogbono soup with meat.")
    print("2, Semolina and efo riro with beef.")
    print("3, Semolina with egusi soup and draw.")
    Semolina=int(input("Select Semolina of choice:"))
    if(Semolina==1):
        print("You selected Semolina and Ogbono soup with meat.")
    elif(Semolina==2):
        print("You selscted Semolina and efo riro with beef.")
    elif(Semolina==3):
        print("You selected Semolina with egusi soup and draw.")
    else:
        print("Plese select a valid command from the list.")
elif(Mainchoice==4):
    print("1, Grilled Chicken breast and laps.")
    print("2, Roasted Full Chicken with tomato ketchup sauce.") 
    print("3, Chicken Barbeque.")
    Chicken=int(input("Select a Chicken of choice:"))
    if(Chicken==1):
        print("You selected Grilled Chicken braest and laps.")
    elif(Chicken==2):
        print("You selected Roasted Full Chicken with tomato ketchup sauce.")
    elif(Chicken==3):
        print("You selected Chicken Barbeque.")
    else:
        print("Please select a valid command from the list.")
else:
    print("Please select a valid number.")

def Canteen():
    return str (Mainchoice)



def Loop():
    r=(input("Would you like to re-select the options again?:"))
    if (r=="yes"):
       Loop()
    if (r=="No"):
       print("Goodbye")
Loop()
```

The code helps a user pre-order food at a canteen.
It displays the food item after the user enters the selected food item. Please what python code line do I add to make the program re-run from the beginning after the user enter "yes".
I have been able to figure out the "No" option.
Any solution would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to use loops? Typically, you'd use a while-loop for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your last line.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        Loop()
```

If you need to quit from here, use Control + C